# Incorrect filename on WWW::Mechanize submission

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

As far as I can read from the [WWW::Mechanize documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.70/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Esubmit_form%28_..._%29), you can do the following to submit a file from a string:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    fields => {
        'UploadedFile' => [[ undef, 'test2.txt', Content => $content ], 1],
    }
);
```

This should submit a file with name `text2.txt`, containing the text in `$content` (in this case, `'The file is a lie.'`).

The request failed with an internal server error, however, so I examined the request that was sent, and found this:

```
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadedFile"; filename="ARRAY(0x9567570)"

The file is a lie.
--xYzZY
```

That is clearly not the filename I specified, so I wonder: Am I doing something wrong, or is the module bugged?

Comment: I did a test and got `filename="ARRAY(0x1f124d8)"` too, dumping `$mech->res` ( `WWW::Mechanize` 1.66 ).

Comment: Does a key of "with_fields" instead of "fields" yield a different result? "with_fields" would help if there is more than one form and no form has been selected.

Comment: `with_fields` gave the same result as `fields`.

Comment: That looks really similar to the LWP base field submission (c/f http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch05_07.htm). Does submitting `fields => {'UploadedFile' => [ undef, 'test2.txt', Content => $content ], upload_field => 1 }`, where upload_field is the name of the form submission field, work correctly?

Comment: @Oesor: I'm unsure as to what you want me to write instead of `upload_field`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in HTML::Form. I have reported it to the author.

In the mean time, if you have HTML::Form version 6.00, you can fix things temporarily by commenting out line 1442 in HTML/Form.pm which reads

```
$old = $self->file unless defined $old;
```